# Pandas - TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a current project, I am among others converting data of a Pandas DataFrame.

When calling the line `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`, I am receiving the error `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`.

I have in this context already checked for some approached relating e.g. to missing parentheses but could not find a matching solution yet. Is there any smart tweak to make this run?

The code section is shown below:

```
import string
import json
import pandas as pd

# Loading and normalising the input file
file = open("sp500.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = pd.DataFrame().fillna

# Datetime conversion
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: please provide example of your data. it's hard to tell where the problem with converting data, with no idea how the data looks like

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.fillna()`

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a type or not reproducible given the `()` are missing in the `fillna()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This amendment is however yielding the following error `TypeError: fillna() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
df = pd.DataFrame().fillna
```

You should have called the `fillna` method.

```
df = df.fillna(method='bfill')
```

Comment: Good idea - when using this line, I am however receiving the following error `ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'.`